Justification for inequality
Suppose $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold with $\text{diam } M \leq D$. Let $u : M \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ be smooth. Define $R_i := 2^{-i}D$ so that $B_i := B(x,R_i)$ for a fixed $x \in M$. In particular, $u(x) = \lim_i\frac{1}{|B_i|}\int_{B_i}u(y)dy$ by the Lebesgue differentiation theorem. Notice that $M = B_0$. Define $u_{B_i} = \frac{1}{|B_i|}\int_{B_i}u(y)dy$.
I am not seeing how to derive the following inequality: $$|u(x)-u_{B_0}| \leq \sum_{i=0}^\infty |u_{B_i}-u_{B_{i+1}}|.$$

You noticed that $u(x) = \lim_{i \to \infty} u_{B_i}$, hence for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $i_0$ such that for all $i \ge i_0$, $|u(x) - u_{B_i}| < \epsilon$. Thus for all such $i$,
$$|u(x) - u_{B_0}| \le \epsilon + |u_{B_i} - u_{B_0}| \le \epsilon + \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} |u_{B_{j+1}} - u_{B_j}| \le \epsilon +  \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} |u_{B_{j+1}} - u_{B_j}|.$$
As this is true for all $\epsilon > 0$, the sought-after inequality follows.
